# Track and delete commands currently in place

Tags: security

I suspect a command has been set up on my PC to send alerts everytime I log on. How do I check if this is the case and then how do I delete it?

Comment: What operating system? Is this in a corporate environment?

Answer (score 0):

First, physically disconnect your system from the network. Then, read `~/.bashrc` (and files sourced from there)( and read `man bash` about `STARTUP FILES` to see others), and inspect the `.desktop` files in `~/.config/autostart/`, and `/etc/xdg/autostart/`.

`locate` can help:

```
locate .desktop
locate autostart
```

will give you the beginning of a list of  files to check.

Since, on ***MY*** system,

```
$ (locate autostart;locate .desktop) | sort -u| wc -l
5947
```

there are 5947 `autostart` or `.desktop` files, this cries out for automation.

First, are the files installed by a known package? If not, further investigation is needed.

```
(locate autostart;locate .desktop) | sort -u| xargs -n1 dpkg -S
```

Use `journalctl -b` to look at the logs, and see if there's anything there.